# Mapping string to enum value

Tags: c, string, enums, esp32, strcmp

In my program, I have an enum that is used for indexing my array members. The reason is that it is much easier for me to understand which parameter I am accessing without knowing its index in the array

```
enum param_enum
{
    AA,
    AB,
    AC,
    AD,
    PARAM_COUNT
};


static int16_t parameters[PARAM_COUNT] =
{
    [AA] = 5, 
    [AB] = 3, 
    [AC] = 4,
    [AD] = 8,
};
```

I can then access any parameter for example:

```
parameters[AA] = 10; // Update AA parameter to value 10.
```

I will be receiving serial commands such as :

```
"AA:15"
```

When I receive this command, I must determine what parameter I need to modify based on the first 2 characters, then skip the 3rd character( because it is just ":" and I dont care about it) and the remaining characters will show the new value)

I wonder if there is any easier way to map the enum to a string

My current method:

```
// line holds the string data
// cmd_size is the length of string data
bool parse_command(char *line, uint16_t cmd_size)
{
printf("data size = %u \n",cmd_size);
char temp_buf[3] = {0};
temp_buf[0] = line[0];
temp_buf[1] = line[1];
printf("temp_buf = %s \n",temp_buf);
if (!strcmp("aa", temp_buf))
    {
        printf("aa: detected \n");
        char temp_storage[5];
        int16_t final_value;
        for(int i = 3;i<=cmd_size; i++){
                temp_storage[i-3]=line[i]; // read data and append to temp bufferfrom the 3rd character till the end of line
                if(line[i] == 0){
                    printf("null termination triggered \n");
                    final_value = strtol(temp_storage,NULL,10); // convert char array to int16_t
                    printf("temp var = %i \n",final_value);             
                }
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

The above method seems to work fine but I do not believe that this is the most appropriate solution for this particular task.

Comment: Is `(char*)param->write.value` null terminated after the `:` or does it also have the value after it? Is the number of characters before the `:` always 2 or variable length?

Comment: what exactly do you mean as "easier"?

Comment: There is a null termination at the end of bluetooth command string. The data is not always length of 2 after the ```:```

Comment: My bad I have left out some crucial information. I have updated my initial question

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind what the actual values of the enumeration constants are, you could define those values to be equivalent to the first two characters of the test string. You can then copy those first two characters into a variable of that `enum` type, which will then adopt the appropriate enumeration directly.

You can define the values using two-character integer literals (like `'BA'`). On little-endian systems (such as Windows), the two characters would be in reverse order; for big-endian systems, they would be in direct order.

Here's an example little-endian implementation:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum param_enum {
    // Reverse byte order from strings for little-endian; keep "as-is" for big-endian...
    AA = 'AA',
    AB = 'BA',
    AC = 'CA',
    AD = 'DA'
};

int main(void)
{
    char test[100];
    while (1) {
        printf("Enter test string (Q to quit): ");
        if (scanf("%99s", test) != 1 || strcmp(test, "Q") == 0) break;
        enum param_enum penum;
        memset(&penum, 0, sizeof(penum));   // To clear any 'upper' bytes
        memcpy(&penum, test, 2);            // Now copy the first 2 byte2
        switch (penum) {
            case AA:
                printf("Code is AA.\n");
                break;
            case AB:
                printf("Code is AB.\n");
                break;
            case AC:
                printf("Code is AC.\n");
                break;
            case AD:
                printf("Code is AD.\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Unknown code.\n");
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

If your compiler doesn't support multicharacter literals (such support is optional, according to the C Standard, IIRC), you can specify equivalent values using hexadecimal constants and the characters' ASCII codes (assuming your platforms uses ASCII encoding), instead:

```c
enum param_enum {
    AA = 0x4141, // 'AA'
    AB = 0x4241, // 'BA'
    AC = 0x4341, // 'CA'
    AD = 0x4441  // 'DA'
};
```

Comment: Or use a macro to construct the value, e.g. '#define TWOCHAR(a, b) (((a) << 8) | (b))` or `#define TWOCHAR(a, b) (((b) << 8) | (a))` depending on endianness. Ideally, the code should avoid endian issues though.

Comment: @IanAbbott Yeah - the macro is nice. On the endianness - presumably, the OP knows what that is for the specific microcontroller, so it *shouldn't* be an issue. (A conditional block defining one or other could be used if multiple systems are being targeted.)

Comment: After looking at this example that you have suggested I realised that it might not work for my particular application because I use my ENUM as indexes for my parameter array therefore I cannot set them to the string. I have forgot to mention this important information in my initial post but I have updated it now

Comment: `|| strcmp(test, "Q") == 0` could instead be another `case`.

Comment: @chux Likely to generate something like: *warning C4063: case '81' is not a valid value for switch of enum 'param_enum'* though (unless you add a `'Q'` as another enumeration).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a look-up table of strings indexed by the param enum, and a function to look up the param enum from the string:

```
enum param_enum {
    AA,
    AB,
    AC,
    AD
};

static const char * const param_prefix[] = {
    [AA] = "AA",
    [AB] = "AB",
    [AC] = "AC",
    [AD] = "AD",
};

#define ARRAYLEN(a) (sizeof (a) / sizeof (a)[0])

int find_param(const char *value, size_t value_len) {
   int i;
   const char *colon = memchr(value, ':', value_len);

   if (!colon) {
       /* not found */
       return -1;
   }

   /* use length up to colon */
   value_len = colon - value;

   for (i = 0; i < ARRAYLEN(param_prefix); i++) {
       if (param_prefix[i]) {
           size_t prefix_len = strlen(param_prefix[i]);

           if (value_len == prefix_len &&
               memcmp(param_prefix[i], value, prefix_len) == 0) {
               /* found */
               return i;
           }
       }
   }
   /* not found */
   return -1;
}
```

Example usage:

```
        // (using 3 for length here, but should use something better)
        int penum = find_param((char*)param->write.value, 3);
        if(penum >= 0) {
            printf("%s parameter need to change\n", param_prefix[penum]);
        }
```

Comment: Hello. I have tried to initialize the following array:
```static const char * const param_prefix[] = {

    [SP] = "SP",

    [DF] = "DF",

    [SS] = "SS",

    [SD] = "SD",

};
```
And the error I am getting : 
```sorry, unimplemented: non-trivial designated initializers not supported```

Comment: Maybe get a better compiler that implements at least C99? Anyway, I have just fixed a bug where I used `param_prefix` instead of `param_prefix[i]` in a couple of places.

Comment: @TheBestPlayer It is confusing because you use the same sort of designated initializer in your question, except mapping to `int16_t` instead of `const char *` values.

Comment: I use int16_t because each parameter value is int16_t type. I am still looking into it. I will try to build a very simple test code that only consists of the enum, my parameter array and the serial data input so I can input a text string

Answer (score 0):

You could use [X Macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) technique.

```
#define PARAM_XMACRO \
    X(AA) \
    X(AB) \
    X(AC) \
    X(AD)


enum param_enum{
#define X(NAME) NAME,
PARAM_XMACRO
#undef X
};

int process() {
    ...
    char *val = (char*)param->write.value;
#define X(NAME) \
    if (strcmp(val, #NAME ":") == 0) {                   \
            printf(#NAME " parameter need to change\n"); \
            return NAME;                                 \
    }
PARAM_XMACRO
#undef X
    return -1;
}
```

It will expand as: (newlines added for clarity)

```
enum param_enum{
AA, AB, AC, AD,
};

int process() {
    ...
    char *val = (char*)param->write.value;

if (strcmp(val, "AA" ":") == 0) {
   printf("AA" " parameter need to change\n");
   return AA;
}
if (strcmp(val, "AB" ":") == 0) {
  printf("AB" " parameter need to change\n");
  return AB;
}
if (strcmp(val, "AC" ":") == 0) {
  printf("AC" " parameter need to change\n");
  return AC;
}
if (strcmp(val, "AD" ":") == 0) {
  printf("AD" " parameter need to change\n");
  return AD;
}
  return -1;
}
```